# Vertically center bootstrap btn in .well class

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a link that I want to center vertically in the `.well` class from the bootstrap framework and am using the class `btn btn-danger` on the anchor tag. Here's the pic below. I tried to use `vertical-align:middle;` but that doesn't seem to work. You can see that the space on the well isn't even on the top and the bottom.

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="well">
   <%= link_to "Remove", thing, method: :delete, style: "font-size: 11px; float:right; ", :class => 'btn btn-danger'%>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the full HTML of where you are using it? We need to set the `display` to `inline-block` before using `vertical-align`.

Comment: I posted it. I also tried to set the `display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle;` and that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: I tried `margin-top:-3px;` which seemed to work, but it's not that robust as a solution as I'd like.

Comment: You need to give `vertical-align: sub` and then try?

Comment: Can you post the HTML Rendered one? or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/613/) .

I've added new classes, so as not to overwrite the default bootstrap.

Answer (score 4):

It appears you shouldn't (or simply can't) vertically align a floating element.

Here is what i suggest :

```
<div class="well mywell">
    <div class="pull-right myfloater">
       <button class="btn btn-danger vcenter">Remove</button>    
    </div>
    <p><!-- things --></p>
</div>
```

```css
.mywell{
   height: 150px;
}
.myfloater {
    line-height: 150px;
}
.vcenter{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The live example : http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/wxM5Z/2/

**Edit**

Better with `line-height`applied to the floating element.