# Bootstrap CSS Alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to get some alignment to work but I am having a hard time being successful. I'm not sure if there is already a CSS style in bootstrap for vertical alignment or not but that is what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a DIV (.well class) with an image and some text inside it. The Image aligns fine as its responsive so the height and placement is good. However, I am trying to align the button and Text vertically in the middle.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6z9skpeh/

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="well wellFriends">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 friendPic">
                <img src="http://oi62.tinypic.com/289j41s.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 friendDetails">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"><strong>Bob Smith</strong>
                        <br><em>Department Name</em>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 pull-right">
                        <!-- Single button -->
                        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Friends <span class="caret"></span>

                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far:
[image]

This is what I am trying to do: [image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers

have a look at the correct answer

Comment: Possible repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184868/vertically-center-bootstrap-btn-in-well-class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this: **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6z9skpeh/2/)**

**css:**

```
.v_align {
    font-size: 0;
}
.v_align >[class*="col"] {
    float: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="row v_align">..</div>
```